# Inequality of the coefficients of a generating function knowing an inequality on the generating function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I know that

> $$\sum c_it^i\leq\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^ah_it^i}{1-\sum\limits_{j=1}^bk_jt^{j+1}}$$

(where the inequality means that $c_i$ is less or equal to the $i$th coefficient of what's on the right)

How can I prove that there exists a real number $\alpha$ such that $c_n\leq \alpha^n$ for $n\geq1$

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand side of the inequality is a rational function.
Using [Partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), it can be written
as a finite sum of terms of the form
$$
\frac{A t^k}{(t - B)^l} = \frac{A' t^k}{(1 - t/B)^l}
$$
where the $B$'s are the different complex roots of the denominator.
Since $1/(1-t/B)^l$ is (apart from some constant factor) the $(l-1)$'th
derivative of the geometric series
$$
\frac{1}{(1 - t/B)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^n}{B^n}
$$
the desired estimate follows.